# Why the Info change the createdDateTime Table's field?

Tags: datetime, timezone, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have to stamp with info a *createdDateTime* field's Table,

I used this simple code:

```
info( strfmt("Date-Time: %1" , myTableDate.createdDateTime)  );
```

On *myTableDate* I have this value: **05/08/2015 12:48:57**

On video in *info* I see this message:

**Date-time: 05/08/2015 10:48:57**

I see two hours less than the value stored in table. The field *createdDateTime* is the standard table's field .

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to correct for [timezone](http://stoneridgesoftware.com/working-with-utcdatetime-functionality-in-dynamics-ax-2012/), as `strFmt` will not do it for you:

```
info( strfmt("Date-Time: %1", DateTimeUtil::applyTimeZoneOffset(myTableDate.createdDateTime, DateTimeUtil::getUserPreferredTimeZone()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need correct a timeZone^ DateTimeUtil::getUserPreferredTimeZone()